# Does using an 'outside' function in a pure function make it impure?

Tags: functional-programming

I come from an imperative background, and have recently begun to delve into functional programming. I'm confused by one concept of pure functions. From what I understand, a pure function is a function that always evaluates to the same result given the same input, and also is a function that does not have side effects.

My confusion stems from using functions inside functions. If I have two functions (pseudocode):

```
function foo(x) { return x+1; }

function bar(x) { return foo(x); }
```

`bar` relies on an outside function, `foo`, to compute its result. Does this render `bar` impure? If so, how can anyone write a program with only pure functions? Does one have to pass a set of utility functions as a parameter (such as count() or map() etc)? I feel like I'm drastically misunderstanding an important aspect of functional programming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. The thing that makes a function impure are side effects. If a function leaks information out to other places than the caller or retrieves information from other places than the caller.

As an example of side effects you have read from keyboard or file and print or store to file. Another one might be storing state inside the function. eg. a counter. that counts how many times you have called it. It doesn't matter if it's local or global so mutating any variables are side effects. Any of this would make a function impure.

Usually you can never make your programs 100% functional. You need small dirty portians that uses input somehow (or else you are calculating exactly the same every time you run it) and some way to display the result (or else why run it in the first place.. unless you use your priogram to head your apartment in case you have a side effect and it's again impure)